# When importing pandas in python v.3.3 i'm getting 'No module named 'pkg_resources'

Tags: python

I have installed numpy, scipy and some other modules including pandas for python v.3.3 win 64 bit.  I can't find this module on the site where i got the other modules it said that I didn't have but I can't find this one to install.  So I am getting the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
        import pandas
      File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
        from pandas.io.api import *
      File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\api.py", line 15, in <module>
        from pandas.io.gbq import read_gbq
      File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\gbq.py", line 10, in <module>
        import pkg_resources ImportError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because your Setuptools installation appears corrupt or isn't in your `PYTHONPATH` - try to [reinstall it](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.9.8#installation-instructions) :

In a terminal, run the following command :

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | python
```

Or with curl :

```
curl https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py | python
```

Comment: Thanks, someone just told me to install setuptools so I went to http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and installed it which is where i got the rest of the modules.  It imports now!